# How to substitute year in loop

Tags: r

High-level view: I have to calculate beta for 20 Stocks for each year 1991:2016. Data given is monthly.

Now, I'm on the step of beta calculation for at least for one stock for the whole time period. My current code looks like:

```
for (i in 1991:2016) {
beta_NESN[i] <- CAPM.beta (window(monthly_ret[,2], "i-01-01", "i+1-01-01"), 
window(monthly_ret[,1], "i-01-01", "i+1-01-01")) 
}
```

Sample of Data:

```
                  .SSMI       NESN.S
1991-02-28   9.59247982   7.99342066
1991-03-31   4.38098619   7.76359676
1991-04-30   0.61047668   1.07850057
1991-05-31   4.78284255   4.77112010
1991-06-30  -4.49401631  -4.65200156
1991-07-31   3.70969856   2.46926126
1991-08-31   0.54275784  -2.23144902
1991-09-30  -4.22842516  -5.11682866
1991-10-31   1.14676046   3.80180672
1991-11-30  -3.70827307  -1.94416816
1991-12-31   2.88537039   5.37442760
1992-01-31   4.87302857   5.10025545
1992-02-29   4.84778148   3.68805355
1992-03-31  -0.18489320   0.84836140
1992-04-30   2.30822934   3.52733664
1992-05-31   2.13126703  -0.20408170
1992-06-30  -3.48607637  -0.61475603
1992-07-31  -3.10463217  -4.30512675
1992-08-31  -2.62008959  -1.95022432
1992-09-30   6.98374565   7.78521263
1992-10-31   1.73118801   3.67651938
1992-11-30   1.04625788   3.82821866
1992-12-31   8.71235635   8.54452060
```

After execution, I face with the following error:

```
Error in merge.xts(..., all = all, fill = fill, suffixes = suffixes) : 
'NA' not allowed in 'index'
```

Could somebody give me an advise how to do it? Part with beta calculation actually works, if i substitute "i" with 1991 and 1992, for instance, but I hope that there another approach exists.

Comment: Try `beta_NESN[i] <- CAPM.beta (window(monthly_ret[,2], paste0(i, "-01-01"), paste0(i+1, "-01-01")), 
window(monthly_ret[,1], paste0(i, "-01-01"), paste0(i+1, "-01-01"))`

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you want to share data in the `r` tag please use `dput()`

Comment: @Hack-R, could you please clarify? Should i put here result of execution dput() on my computer, shouldn't I?

Comment: Yes that's correct. If it's too long you can always sample or subset your data before using that command. dput allows us to easily reproduce your data including classes and unused factor levels etc

Comment: @ImranAli, thanks a lot! it works. Still i have another problem with loop, because it can be executed, but my output vector consists of tons NA. As i understand, my loop executes for 1:2016 years, but i don't understand why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
   for (i in 1991:2016) {
    beta_NESN[i] <- CAPM.beta (window(monthly_ret[,2], paste0(i, "-01-01") , paste0(i+1, "-01-01")), 
    window(monthly_ret[,1], paste0(i, "-01-01") , paste0(i+1, "-01-01") )) 
    }
```